# Necesito resolver una condicion de una tabla de web scrapping

Tags: r, rstudio, scraping

Hice un raspado de la web de un url y esto salió a la vista de cómo la figura (1) con sus respectivos espacios de filas y son mas 4000 filas anexadas con sus 2 espacios por cada ítem necesito eliminarla, ademas si es posible me gustaría agrupar como se muestra en la siguiente tabla (2) por , ¿se puede hacer? figura (1)

figura (1) :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

figura (2) :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les paso el código  que estaba avanzando :

```
url2<-read_html("http://pe.kairosweb.com/resultado-busqueda.php?prodname=a&x=0&y=0") tables<-html_table(url2,fill=TRUE) tables5<-tables[[5]]

tables5_1<-tbl_df(tables5)

n<-nrow(tables5_1)

cuenta<-1:n

tables5_1d<-data.frame(cuenta,tables5_1)

View(tables5_1d)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voy a plantearte una solución a la manera `tidyverse`, por que entiendo que para esta manipulación de los datos, es una forma mucho más clara. De cualquier manera la idea puede llevarse a código R base sin problema.

En primer lugar, vamos a trabajar con la tabla `tables[[5]]` en crudo, que esta estructurada así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede apreciar, cada "producto" es un grupo de filas separadas por lineas en blanco. En primer lugar, vamos a limpiar un poco los datos y agregar información útil, básicamente:

1. Generaremos un identificador único de cada bloque para poder luego identificar cada "producto"
2. Numeraremos cada fila dentro de cada bloque ya que para identificar el nombre del producto, iremos a constatar la primer fila de cada bloque
3. Por último eliminamos las filas innecesarias

Esto en `tidyverse` lo podemos implementar así:

```
library("tidyverse")

df <- tables[[5]] %>% 
  mutate(id_producto = cumsum(X1 == "")) %>%      # Generamos un id por bloque
  filter(X1 != "",
         X1 != "PRESENTACIONES") %>%              # Quitamos filas en blanco y titulos
  mutate(nr=ave(X1, id_producto, FUN=seq_along))  # generamos un numerdador interno del bloque
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya tenemos los datos mucho más ordenados para la última etapa. Ahora vamos a:

1. Obtener los productos (son aquellos donde el número de fila `nr` es igual a 1)
2. Obtener las presentaciones (es el caso contrario del punto anterior)
   3 Con las dos bases separadas, podemos unirlas en una sola, mediante un `left join`

Código:

```
df %>% 
  filter(nr == 1) %>%
  select(VENTA = X1, id_producto, nr) -> productos

df %>% 
  filter(nr != 1) %>%
  mutate(PRESENTACIONES = X1,
         PVF = X2,
         PPS = X3) %>% 
  select(id_producto, nr, PRESENTACIONES, PVF, PPS) -> presentaciones

productos %>% 
  left_join(presentaciones, by="id_producto") %>% 
  select(VENTA, PRESENTACIONES, PVF, PPS) -> df_final
```

Resultado final:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio , me ayudo mucho!